# Google Tag Manager and Single Page APP: How to read a DOM Element?

Tags: javascript, dom, single-page-application, google-tag-manager

I want to create a variable on my GTM to store a DOM element. I've tried a custom javascript, for example:

```
function(){
  return document.querySelector('.room__price-value').innerText;
}
```

But nothing, on GTM preview I see always NULL. I think the issue was the single page app.
And I can't involve the programmers.

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: Is the tag that uses the variable executed before or after the content is rendered? Especially when the GTM snippet is just pasted into the base template of an SPA it is sometimes executed before the DOM is even there.  That'S what you should check first.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that when in preview, you check the value of your variable on every event on the left.
2. Make sure when you execute `document.querySelector('.room__price-value').innerText;` in your console, you actually get the result you're expecting.
3. Change the code until you get the result in the local console.
4. Make sure your timing is good, as Eike mentioned in the comment.

What you're doing there seems right. That's pretty much how you do DOM scrape in GTM when front-end devs aren't available. If the suggestions still don't work for you, give us more info on what you're doing, on how your DOM looks like, what your debugging showed and such. As much potentially useful context as you can.

Comment: I think you and @Eike are right about timing, I see DOM loaded but my info show next, after some history event. Is there anyway to intercept a DOM element in this situation ? 
https://i.imgur.com/n2jRMlv.jpg

Comment: no, you have to move your trigger to a later time. Either by using actual future event, or if there's no such event, then fire it with a timeout after a user clicks the CTA. Well, you can also try using the event visibility trigger: https://i.imgur.com/xAux2DX.png There are actually many ways to solve it.

Comment: Perfect @BNazaruk, it works using visibility trigger. Thank you!